# Find the element that has the largest second element in nested list

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list like this:

```
 car_cost = [[carA, 10000], [carB, 20000], [carC, 30000]]
```

how can I effectively find the element that has the maximum second element?

in this case should be getting a index 2, or the element

```
[carC, 30000]
```

I can find the max second element value by

```
 max(car_cost, key = lambda x:x[1])
```

But I don't know how to do the rest effectively, please show me how can I do this

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max(car_cost, key = lambda x:x[1])` return a list with the `car` and the number. You can get it with index 0

```
item = max(car_cost, key=lambda x: x[1])
print(item[0]) # carC
```

Answer (score 0):

@Guy has the simplest answer, but you can also do:

```
print(next(iter(max(car_cost, key=lambda x: x[1]))))
```

Or one-liner version of @Guy's solution:

```
print(max(car_cost, key=lambda x: x[1])[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

following the logic you propose, this would be a possible solution.

We get the maximum element in a copy list, and we delete it and again we look for the maximum. Obviously this is not the most profitable but serves to get out of the way.

I recommend you read the following article. It will help you understand the correct logic.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-find-second-largest-number-in-a-list/

And here is code:

```
carA = 1
carB = 2
carC = 3

car_cost = [[carA, 10000], [carB, 20000], [carC, 30000]]
copy = car_cost
copy.remove(max(car_cost, key = lambda x:x[1]))
print(max(copy, key = lambda x:x[1]))
```

Comment: Try to print ```car_cost``` and ```copy``` and you'll see that ```car_cost``` was changed too. When you do ```copy = car_cost``` you just copy the pointer not the value. You should use ```copy_ = car_cost[:]```, ```copy = copy.deepcopy(car_cost)``` or ```copy = list(car_cost)```. In the second case I'll recomend you ti rename ```copy``` variable to ```copy_``` or smth else to avoid naming troubles

Comment: oooh. thats right. but only i want to show an example how do that easy. but you right